# Typeahead Array as valueKey

Tags: jquery, typeahead, typeahead.js

I was using typeahead successfully until I tried to pass an array as a valuekey. It works for everything until the Tag. I'd like to be able to type "Astronomy" or "Science" to get either of the values of that array in Tag. Am I missing something, or does typeahead not support this?  Is there a different way I can achieve this?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sr4136/gcUTj/

```
$(".programs-search .text").typeahead([
    {
        name: 'programs',
        local: json,
        limit: 10,
        valueKey: 'tag',
        template: '<p>{{name}} - {{degree}}</p>',
        engine: Hogan
    }
]);
```

Here is the object:

```
var json=[{
    "name":"Astronomy and Physics",
    "degree":"BS",
    "school":"SAD",
    "discipline":"The Sciences",
    "location":"Classroom",
    "tag":["Astronomy","Science"]
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value key should be "name", and what you call "tag" should be called "tokens". That's it.